# No style after migrating Joomla to localhost

Tags: joomla, migration, localhost

I'm a total newbie with Joomla. 
I'm the new man in charge of a website and they want a full redesign.

I have already downloaded everything by ftp into my WampServer and exported the BD.
I changed the configuration.php to point my new BD.

I could access the web but I got lots of Deprecated Errors so I turned off the display_errors in the php.ini

Now I can finally see te content of the web but with no templates and no style.

Any idea what's happening?

(I'm not sure what version of Joomla it was working with.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing I would do is wipe out what you have moved. Then go download and install Akeeba backup. Take a full site backup, then use that to install on localhost. Doing this will make your life a lot easier when it comes to moving the site easily. If the site has issues after moving it this way, then you can pretty much bet it's a server configuration issue and not a Joomla issue.

Next thing you need to do is determine what version of Joomla you have. The 1.5.x series should have the version in the admin in the top right. The 1.6/1.7/2.5 series will have it in the admin in the footer. You can probably check the source on the front end and it will tell you in the meta generator tag. Unless you are on 2.5.2, then you will want to start planning for a migration to the newest version. 1.5 reaches end of life next month and 1.6/1.7 are no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks Brent, when I go to the admin page there is an interface set by the previous company (SSIT) and the only relevant data I can extract is:  Versión de PHP:  5.2.9
Servidor Web:          DinaHTTPd Server
Interfaz servidor web a PHP:  apache2handler
Versión de SSIT:  SSIT 1.0.15 Stable [ Daytime ] 22 February 2008 23:00 UTC

Comment: Bummer. That is bad news. Your site is on version 1.0.15. The 1.0.x series was dropped a couple of years ago. Depending on the size of the site, it may be easier to start with a fresh 2.5.x install and rebuilt from the ground up. Otherwise you will have to to a migration from 1.0 to 1.5, then another migration from 1.5 to 2.5. Modern extensions are 1000x better than anything ever written for 1.0.x, I would just build new and save all the trouble. You will be way better off in the long run.

Comment: Is there a way of using the old DB on the 2.5.x version? And  would it be that difficult to do both migrations? It sounds to me like I'd still be saving hours of work, especially considering I'm a newbie.

Comment: There are significant changes to the DB from 1.0 to 1.5 and then again from 1.5 to 2.5. Your best bet would be to export basic article info into a CSV, then import it back in to 2.5. Check the Joomla extension directory, you should find a CSV import that works on 2.5